# Unable to install on a Lenovo V460

Tags: 10.10, installation, troubleshooting, lenovo

I tried installing Ubuntu 10.10 on a Lenovo V460. I selected a separate drive for it and also created a swap area, but after the copying of files is over and when it displays "Ready When You Are ..." my laptop hangs.

How to solve this? Is this a problem with my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

First, try with different installation CD:

- Ubuntu 10.04 desktop
- Ubuntu 10.10 Alternative

You can find both images from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.10/).

Second, if different CD isn't helping, file a bug report to [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/).

Third, you can try with another distribution, for example [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/) or [Debian](http://www.debian.org/) (Ubuntu is based on Debian).

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if you have SATA drive. Go to BIOS setup and turn on the IDE emulation and this would work. I had similar kind of problem with my new HP ProBook.

Comment: By the way, the theme of this site is so awesome. The font and all that when you're on Ubuntu 10.10. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, go into BIOS, and turn off switchable graphics (dedicated), then you can install. Though it won't work that well on that laptop, at least you'll be able to install.